# Put repeating codes in a variable in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I want to put some commands into a variable, so that I can write the variable instead of repeating the commands over and over:

```
myvar = \once \override Beam.beam-thickness = #tremBeamThickness \override Beam.gap = #3
```

This is throwing an error when I use it like `\myvar` in my ly file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two `\override`s are separate elements. Your code is an assignment `myvar = \once \override Beam.beam-thickness = #tremBeamThickness` followed by a spurious override `\override Beam.gap = #3` that is at the top level, trying to make up an entire score by itself. You should put braces around them to unite them into a single "sequential expression" that you can then put into a variable, i.e.,

```
myvar = {
  \once \override ...
  \once \override ...
}
```